# how to replace/change image button programmatically android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I have an image button on my view which i need to change after user interaction. I dont find nothing like `myImageButton.setDrawable` Here is my xml for the button i want to change:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttons_background"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_play" />
```

The only line I need to change `android:src="@drawable/btn_play"` to `android:src="@drawable/btn_stop"` programmatically. Can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
setImageResource for the image button
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```java
myImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_stop);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_stop, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works for Button.

Answer (score 2):

Use

`setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_stop);`