# ImageButton set drawable using @android:drawable/ programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, imagebutton

I have the following image button in my XML layout

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/show_only_checked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    tools:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />
```

Great. Works perfect. But I want to toggle it in the onClick() event to the up version of this drawable in code. Everytime the user clicks the button, I want to toggle back and forth between the up and down arrow. I appear to be too dense to figure this out. I have tried the following code, with no luck.

```
if (ShowOnlyChecked) {
    view.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"));
} else {
    view.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Part of my problem was how to reference "android.R..." to the drawable. The other was which method to call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imagebutton change programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233062/imagebutton-change-programmatically)

Comment: Hii There is lot of similar question already answered.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233062/imagebutton-change-programmatically

Comment: Check this too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526112/how-to-replace-change-image-button-programmatically-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will change the view's background image.

Here is how to set the button image:

```
((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_float);
```

Comment: Ok, both this and Ehsan were almost correct. Here is what worked: ((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);

Comment: Well of course you can call setImageResource() with any resource you want

Comment: I didn't know how to get to "android.R.drawable...", that was one hurdle that is new for me.

Comment: glad you sorted it out !

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 imageButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ImageButton component, you set things in runtime wrongly, because Drawable.createFromPath provides a path to drawable as say absolute path or the desired path. 
If you want to set an arrow, then try to add different resolution images of arrow based on resource folder 
or 
`youId.setBackgroundResource(android:R.drawable.id)`
 or get images from here

https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline